# Vector Drawable in the circle

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

is there an easy way to generate Vector Drawable that is a circle with the icon inside from the existing vector drawable?

Example:
[image: existing vector drawable]

[image: generated vector drawable, circle with empty icon inside]

Comment: use background property

Comment: how do you want yo use that vector drawable? from an xml layout file? or at runtime from java code?

Comment: I would like to solve it as simple as possible by generating ready to use VectorDrawable. No code or drawable modifications.

Comment: Just download [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) and learn the basics. And if you don't want a programmatic solution, then this is off-topic for Stack Overflow. :)

Answer (score 22):

I would suggest something like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_brightness_1_black_24dp"

    />
    <item
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_call_black_24dp"
        android:top="20dp"
        android:bottom="20dp"
        android:left="20dp"
        android:right="20dp"
        />

</layer-list>
```

The resources with ids ic_brightness_1_black_24dp and ic_call_black_24dp are imported vector drawables.

ic_brightness_1_black_24dp:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#303F9F"
        android:pathData="M12,12m-10,0a10,10 0,1 1,20 0a10,10 0,1 1,-20 0"/>
</vector>
```

and ic_call_black_24dp:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M6.62,10.79c1.44,2.83 3.76,5.14 6.59,6.59l2.2,-2.2c0.27,-0.27 0.67,-0.36 1.02,-0.24 1.12,0.37 2.33,0.57 3.57,0.57 0.55,0 1,0.45 1,1V20c0,0.55 -0.45,1 -1,1 -9.39,0 -17,-7.61 -17,-17 0,-0.55 0.45,-1 1,-1h3.5c0.55,0 1,0.45 1,1 0,1.25 0.2,2.45 0.57,3.57 0.11,0.35 0.03,0.74 -0.25,1.02l-2.2,2.2z"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: Yes, that's the idea, however, I would like to solve it as simple as possible by generating ready to use VectorDrawable. No code or drawables modifications.

Answer (score 8):

Since nobody has mentioned how to do this using vector drawing as the question says here is the way to do it.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="144dp"
    android:height="144dp"
    android:viewportWidth="144"
    android:viewportHeight="144">
  
  <path
      android:pathData="M72,72m-50,0a50,50 0,1 1,100 0a50,50 0,1 1,-100 0"
      android:strokeWidth="9"
      android:fillColor="#00000000"
      android:strokeColor="#fff"/>

 </vector>




M72,72m -> circle's center coordinates
50` -> the circle's radius
100` -> circle's diameter
strokeWidth -> the ring's thickness
```

- To make it into a disc instead of a ring change the `fillColor`
- To make your circle half the size change all occurrences of 50 to 25 and all occurrences of 100 to 50. Change accordingly for other sizes.
- To move the circle around inside the viewport change the circle's coordinates (the `72` numbers)

These numbers obviously are related to the viewport size. 72 is the center for 144 which is the defined viewport size in this case. To center it in a 200 viewport size you would need to use 100

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Actually it's quite simple, you just need to include both paths in a single vector, so with your paths it will look like the following:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#303F9F"
        android:pathData="M12,12m-10,0a10,10 0,1 1,20 0a10,10 0,1 1,-20 0"/>

    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M6.62,10.79c1.44,2.83 3.76,5.14 6.59,6.59l2.2,-2.2c0.27,-0.27 0.67,-0.36 1.02,-0.24 1.12,0.37 2.33,0.57 3.57,0.57 0.55,0 1,0.45 1,1V20c0,0.55 -0.45,1 -1,1 -9.39,0 -17,-7.61 -17,-17 0,-0.55 0.45,-1 1,-1h3.5c0.55,0 1,0.45 1,1 0,1.25 0.2,2.45 0.57,3.57 0.11,0.35 0.03,0.74 -0.25,1.02l-2.2,2.2z"/>

</vector>
```

The result will obviously depend on sizes of paths in relation to each other, and since scaling them without a graphical tool is a pain, [DimDim's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49392438/2911458) with a `layer-list` is easier to implement.

Comment: I think mapping both path's values with viewport width and height will not create a problem

Answer (score -1):

Use this way,
[image]
I tried in my own and it's working fine. It looks like this.
[image]

for button_round:
[image]